# Right shoe getting abraded abnormally

Tags: clothing, walking

Inside of my right shoe, on the part where the back of the heel touches the cloth of the shoe, there is an abnormal abrasion that wears away on the cloth. This has happened on multiple pairs of shoes and I am not exactly sure what is causing this. I have attached a picture of the place where it abrades.

[image]

Now, it's only the right shoe and it's always that same spot. I've been putting thick paper as padding in that area. But I would like to know if there is a better way to deal with this and what exactly I am doing wrong to cause that abrasion as I am not able to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could see an orthopedist. He might give you specially fittet shoe inserts.

Comment: I thought of that, but I feel as if it's something to do with the way I walk as this only happens with the right shoe.

Comment: Yes, he will be able to tell you and maybe counter it with custom-made insoles, or recommend to wear a slightly different type of shoe or physio-therapy exercises ... Or whatever else is in his arsenal. I don't feel like it will be something major like a wooden leg tough ;) (My left leg is a bit weaker. So that's my experience ...)